# React Native Webview Error while running library having react-native-webview in a React Application

Tags: react-native, npm, webview, react-native-webview

I have created a react native Library which is using Webview. This is the package.json of the library.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-native-webview": "*"
  },
```

So I installed the library using the npm package with the command `npm install packagename`.
It correctly installs the library and the react-native-webview module in the app's node_modules. When I am running the application I am getting the error when I am invoking the library.

**Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager.**

Comment: Please share your package.json file 
if you have use any npm, they are use old webview then this type of error are generate

Comment: I have created the npm package.

Comment: package.json of library or application?

Comment: i have created  react native sdk which is using react native webview. When I am using it in my application I am getting the above error

Comment: Make sure to link the package with `react-native link react-native-webview`.